# Search activity won't launch?

Tags: android, android-searchmanager

I have implemented a search system in my app, and the search bar appears, but when enter is pressed the search activity doesn't load.

As well as this, the text typed into the search box is black. The action bar is also black, so is there a way to make it white on API 14+?

My MainActivity:

```
package com.liamwli.spotify.spotifycommunity;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ProgressBar progress;
    WebView wv;
    WebSettings wvs;
    String url, prefix;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    ActionBar ab;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        editor = prefs.edit();

        ab = getActionBar();

        ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pBProgress);
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wVPage);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (!url.contains("community.spotify.com")
                        && !url.contains("facebook.com")
                        && !url.contains("spotify.com")) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                }

                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        });
        wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (newProgress < 100
                        && progress.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE) {
                    progress.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);

                }
                progress.setProgress(newProgress);
                if (newProgress == 100) {
                    progress.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);

                }

                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
            }

        });
        wvs = wv.getSettings();

        if (prefs.getBoolean("javascript_enabled", true)) {
            wvs.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wvs.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
            wvs.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
        wvs.setSupportZoom(true);
        wvs.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

        if (prefs.getBoolean("desktop_mode", false)) {
            prefix = "/?device-view=desktop";
        } else {
            prefix = "/?device-view=mobile";

        }

        url = "http://community.spotify.com" + prefix;

        Intent liam = getIntent();
        if (liam.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_VIEW) {
            Uri data = liam.getData();
            URL urlurl = null;
            try {
                urlurl = new URL(data.getScheme(), data.getHost(),
                        data.getPath());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException("Malformed URL Given");
            }
            url = urlurl.toString() + prefix;

        }

        if (url == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("URL Null");

        wv.loadUrl(url);

    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(this);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search)
                .getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the
                                                    // widget;
                                                    // expand it by default

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_back:

            if (wv.canGoBack()) {
                wv.goBack();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Can't Go Back!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

            break;
        case R.id.menu_forward:

            if (wv.canGoForward()) {
                wv.goForward();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Can't Go Forward!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

            break;
        case R.id.menu_refresh:

            wv.reload();

            break;
        case R.id.menu_settings:

            Intent i = new Intent(this, PrefActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

            break;
        case R.id.menu_search:

            onSearchRequested();

            break;
        case android.R.id.home:

            wv.loadUrl("http://community.spotify.com" + prefix);

            break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

}
```

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.liamwli.spotify.spotifycommunity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.liamwli.spotify.spotifycommunity.StartActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.liamwli.spotify.spotifycommunity.MainActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            tools:ignore="ExportedActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.liamwli.spotify.spotifycommunity.MAINACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.liamwli.spotify.spotifycommunity.PostUrl"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.liamwli.spotify.spotifycommunity.POSTURL" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.liamwli.spotify.spotifycommunity.PrefActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filer>
                <action android:name="com.liamwli.spotify.spotifycommunity.PREFACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.cetagory.PREFERENCE" />
            </intent-filer>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.liamwli.spotify.spotifycommunity.ClearData"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.liamwli.spotify.spotifycommunity.CLEARDATA" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.liamwli.spotify.spotifycommunity.SearchActivity"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="com.liamwli.spotify.spotifycommunity.MySuggestionProvider"
            android:authorities="com.liamwli.spotify.spotifycommunity.MySuggestionProvider"
            android:exported="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My SearchActivity:

```
package com.liamwli.spotify.spotifycommunity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.SearchRecentSuggestions;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SearchActivity extends Activity {

    WebView wv;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    String prefix;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        editor = prefs.edit();

        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wVPage);

        if (prefs.getBoolean("desktop_site", false)) {
            prefix = "/?device-view=desktop";
        } else {
            prefix = "/?device-view=mobile";
        }

        // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            SearchRecentSuggestions suggestions = new SearchRecentSuggestions(
                    this, MySuggestionProvider.AUTHORITY,
                    MySuggestionProvider.MODE);
            suggestions.saveRecentQuery(query, null);
            doMySearch(query);
        }
    }

    private void doMySearch(String query) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        wv.loadUrl("http://community.spotify.com/t5/forums/searchpage/tab/message?q="
                + query + prefix);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(this);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_nosearch, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_back:

            if (wv.canGoBack()) {
                wv.goBack();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Can't Go Back!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

            break;
        case R.id.menu_forward:

            if (wv.canGoForward()) {
                wv.goForward();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Can't Go Forward!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

            break;
        case R.id.menu_refresh:

            wv.reload();

            break;
        case R.id.menu_settings:

            Intent i = new Intent(this, PrefActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

            break;

        case android.R.id.home:

            wv.loadUrl("http://community.spotify.com" + prefix);

            break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

}
```

I don't receive a force close - it just doesn't launch the search activity.

Also, what permission should I set for the final provider? The android system must be able to execute it,